# A question regarding the 'Tumbleweed' badge

Tags: discussion

Is gaining the 'Tumbleweed' badge a thing which I should feel honoured to receive, just because it is a badge? Or, to be awarded with that badge is not what that one desires participating on Christianity.SE?

Comment: Good or bad, it's an impressive achievement for this site. >_>

Comment: It was designed to make you feel better for having a post that no one is interested in.

Comment: @fredsbend, really? How could I feel *better*, if no one wants to read a question I asked?

Comment: All: [this is the question in, er, question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20114/saint-januarius-miracle-of-the-annual-liquefaction-of-his-blood).

Comment: One reason may be because it's a **huge unattributed quote from Wikipedia.** SE questions are best if they are pithy with *just* enough background information to provide context. And always, always, attribute anything you copy: preferably with a link to the online text if it is online.

Comment: @Elberich Yes, what Andrew says. It is too long. I don't even want to read it because of that. If you could cut 10 of your 14 paragraphs you would get more people interested in it.

Answer (score 5):

[I asked this over on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47369/144439). The highest voted answer was:

> It encourages you to ask questions even if you think they are a little out of the mainstream. In this regard it is a positive thing, though not something I would be too excited about.

FWIW [you're not the only one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed).

Comment: It is one of those bittersweet badges. "Sweet I got a badge! Oh, its the tumbleweed."

Comment: I will note that two out of the other three given the tumbleweed now have accepted answers. And one of them is pretty darn good ;)